# Запятая между частями главного предложения в СПП

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, спп, сложное-предложение

*Когда глаза собеседника бегают из стороны в сторону — это инстинктивно вызывает недоверие[,] и с таким человеком не хочется иметь дело.*

Является ли первая и вторая части главного предложения однородными по отношению к придаточному, что предполагает отсутствие запятой, или здесь вторая часть скорее выражает следствие из первой части без связи с придаточным — запятая ставится?

Comment: "Глаза бегают по сторонам" - так не говорят.

Comment: Угрем ускользал от прямых ответов, но **глаза бегали по сторонам**. [Н. А. Островский. Как закалялась сталь (1930-1934)]

Comment: Но в подавляющем большинстве случаев в Нацкорпусе глаза просто **бегают**. Мне кажется, "глаза бегают по сторонам" — плеоназм. Однако если убрать "по сторонам", то предложение не звучит, его нужно перестроить: *Когда у собеседника бегают глаза — это ...*

Comment: Ну, великий писатель Николай Островский... Не помню у кого "коза кричала нечеловеческим голосом".

Comment: У писателя Уксусова (http://lib.ru/DOWLATOW/dowlatow.txt?wmode=opaque)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, здесь логическая цепочка: глаза бегают -> вызывает недоверие ->  не хочется иметь дела. "Здесь вторая часть скорее выражает следствие из первой части без связи с придаточным — запятая ставится".